# Android Activity to another Activity, while you have setting activity

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to go to another activity, but my setting activity is preventing to go there. How do I fix that?

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var gettext: EditText? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        gettext = findViewById(R.id.text2)
       // val intent = intent
        val action = intent.action
        val type = intent.type
        val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_submit)
```

//this part is what I want to go to another activity, while still have setting activity

```
button.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this,com.example.testing1.DecryptVerify::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        if (Intent.ACTION_SEND == action && type != null) {

            handleSendText(intent)

        }

    }



private fun handleSendText(intent: Intent) {
        val sharedText = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)
        if (sharedText != null) {

            // showing the text in edittext
            gettext?.setText(sharedText)
        }
    }
```

//I want to stay, while when I run it and click button on the top one

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
       when (item.itemId) {
          R.id.action_settings -> {
               val intent = Intent(this, com.example.testing1.SettingsActivity::class.java
               )
                startActivity(intent)
           }
        }
      return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
   }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        val menuInflater = menuInflater
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu)
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }


    }
```

Do I need to some form if-else?

Comment: what is exactly NOT working? menu passing to `SettingsActivity`, onClick passing to `DecryptVerify`...?

Comment: I fix my problem. I mess somewhere in my code that did not call into another activity. it is all good